# if commands in python - roulette simulator

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I am trying to request a specific betting amount with a minimum, maximum and specific increments. When I run the following code, the program loops over every element in the array rather than stopping.

```
from pylab import *
import random
bank = 20000
betrange=range(100,20100,100)    
print "Hello Kathy, welcome to the Golden Brighton casino. We have reserved a high roller table for your bank of 20,000. How much would you like to bet per spin? The table has a 100 minimum bet with a maximum of 20,000."
print "The available legal bets are as follows:"
bet=raw_input("Place your bets please:") 
for i in range(len(betrange)):
    if betrange[i] == bet: 
       print bet,"Your bet has been accepted, can you make a million?"
       break
    else:
       print bet,"Please enter a legal bet. The table minimum is 100, with a maximum of 20000 in increments of 100."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code would be better off as an expression than a loop:

```
if 100 <= bet <= 20000 and bet%100 == 0:
    print bet,"Your bet has been accepted"
else:
    print bet,"Please enter a valid bet"
```

Comment: Well, in my very old (BBC BASIC) Roulette simulator, I just used a GOTO, but out of [fear of raptor attack](http://xkcd.com/292/), I will advise that you enclose the `bet=raw_input(...)` and conditional inside a `while 1` loop, and add a `break` to the "accepted" side.